# Disk space difference about text and varchar

Tags: mysql, database

There is some disk space difference from these 2 fields: TEXT and VARCHAR ?

I need to use a field to store URL but my hosting support varchar up to 333 chars.

Here is my table:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `urls` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `first_citizen_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title_citizen` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `title_source` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(333) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `link_image` varchar(333) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link` (`link`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Explain exactly what you are doing, what you want to do, and give us the exact error message you get.

Comment: I need to use a field to store URL but my hosting support varchar up to 333chars. So I could use a TEXT field but maybe it use much more disk space and in this case it is not a good solution for me. That's all :)

Comment: Click "edit" below the question to update it.

Comment: How has your hosting service managed to restrict the maximum size of VARCHAR, which is 65,535? Did they compile a custom modified MySQL build just to annoy customers?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem but I get this error: "#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes" . Above I have inserted the table, please see it :(

Comment: So how can I resolve ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#idp52565952) chapter:

> In the following table, M represents the declared column length in
>   characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string
>   types. L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string
>   value.
>
> `VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)`    L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255
>   bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes
>
> `BLOB, TEXT`  L + 2 bytes, where L < 2<sup>16</sup>

Whatever, I'm pretty sure that your hosting service is not limiting anything. You probably have a table with lots of large columns and just hit the [maximum row size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html).

Comment: you right :D but now how can I use a varchar(1000) field for example ?

Comment: I have insert the table above, please see it :(

Comment: @xRobot - So, what happens exactly when you create a table where `varchar(333)` is replaced with e.g. `varchar(2048)`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is
Text is a pointer to a system table that holds it and other types of Blob (Binary Large OBject).
So you have the overhead of the pointer, 4 or 8 bytes per not null text field.